# Why my panel is not in my div in Firefox?

Tags: html, css

This is a website of my friend and he wants to know why there is a problem in firefox, there are some problem in the CSS file .

https://www.jouwhost.nl/clientarea.php (Look the client area with firefox). 
In chrome i have no problem .

#### HTML

```
<form class="form-stacked" action="dologin.php" method="post">
 <div class="logincontainer">
  <fieldset class="control-group">
   <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="username">Emailadres:</label>
    <div class="controls">
     <input id="username" class="input-xlarge" type="text" name="username">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="password">Wachtwoord:</label>
     <div class="controls">
      <input id="password" class="input-xlarge" type="password" name="password">
     </div>
   </div>
   <div align="center">
    <div class="loginbtn">
     <input class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit" value="Inloggen">
    </div>
    <div class="rememberme">
     <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme">
     <strong>Herinner mij</strong>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <p>
     <a href="pwreset.php">Klik hier om een nieuw wachtwoord aan te vragen</a>
    </p>
  </div>
 </fieldset>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
form {
    margin: 0;
}

.whmcscontainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
.whmcscontainer .contentpadded {
    padding: 15px;
}

.whmcscontainer .halfwidthcontainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}
.whmcscontainer .logincontainer {
    margin: 30px auto 100px;
    width: 280px;
}
.whmcscontainer .logincontainer label {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `overflow: hidden;` of `.wrapper` and it will work.

Comment: thanks it works . Just another problem, do you know why the green block is not in the menu ? It's the same it works in chrome but not in Firefox . The Klanten paneel .

Comment: Because there is not enough space due to another font rendering of the menu.

Comment: Yes i guess it's gceause of that. But why it's working in chrome and not in firefox ? ^^ It's weird ?

Comment: As I said: It's another font rendering and thus it needs more space. Please set my answer as correct answer when it works with it.